# How to use Windows to create a bootable Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, macbook, osx-yosemite

I have Windows 8.1 and my another device is MacBook Air (Mid 2011).  My MacBook Air’s OS didn’t startup and I unintentionally erased my MacBook HD partition. Now, I only could access my restore partition of my MacBook Air.

I have the Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) from the Apple app store on my external drive, but I don’t know how to create a bootable flash drive to clean install the OS.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many free ways to create macOS bootable USB drive on Windows, Transmac is not a great ideal as it's not free.

Clover Boot Disk includes tools and partition images to help you create macOS Mojave bootable USB from Windows in just a few clicks.
https://www.aioboot.com/en/clover-boot-disk/

Create A Bootable MacOS Catalina Installer Drive - Hard Way
https://www.sysgeeker.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-catalina-installer-drive.html#tip4

Answer (score 1):

Guide from [PureInfoTech.com](http://pureinfotech.com/2014/12/05/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/):

> **Things you’ll need:** a trial copy of TransMac, a USB flash drive with at least 8GB of storage (16GB is recommended), and a copy of OS X
>   (DMG file). Now that you have all the necessary ingredients, you’re
>   ready to make a Mac OS X bootable USB using the DMG file of the
>   operating system with the steps below.
>
> **Instructions**
>
> 1. [Download and install a copy of TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm), which is the software that will make everything happen. TransMac is a paid software, but it
>      has a 15-day trial solution, that give us more than enough time to
>      move the DMG files to the USB drive from Windows. (Though, if you want
>      to support the developer, you can purchase the full version.)
> 2. Insert the USB drive that you’ll use to fix your installation of OS X. Remember that all the data in the USB will be erased. Make sure you
>      take off any important documents.
> 3. Right-click the **TransMac** software icon and **Run as administrator**. You’ll be prompted to Enter Key or Run because we’ll
>      be using it once, click **Run**.
> 4. On the left pane, you’ll see all the Windows PC drives listed, **right-click the USB drive** you’re intending to use to re-install Apple’s OS and click **Restore with Disk Image.**
> 5. In the warning dialog box, click **Yes**.
> 6. Use the *Restore Disk Image to Drive* dialog box to **browse for the DMG file** with the installation files for Mac OS X Yosemite in
>      this case, and click **OK** to create a bootable USB of the operating
>      system.
>
> Now, you’ll have to wait a long time. No kidding. It could take one or
>   two hours to complete the process depending on your computer and other
>   variables.

Comment: So since you're self-answering I'm assuming the above worked for you and you now have OS X up and running on your Macbook?

Comment: This did NOT work for me. I got a prohibition sign when attempting to boot from a USB created through transmac with the GPT. I followed the procedure precisely. I had to use Carbon Copy Cloner to get past that. https://superuser.com/questions/1052037/macbook-pro-does-not-boot-prohibition-screen-does-not-see-hard-drive-blink/1058012#1058012