# Installing Ubuntu on Mac -- using boot stick built from Windows Machine

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu

I was gifted a Mac recently, but have no way to validate my access to the MacOS. I want to install Ubuntu, but all of the directions I've found say to build a boot USB drive using the Mac... So, here is where I need help...

I want to build a USB boot drive on my Windows PC that can be used to boot Ubuntu on a Mac. Am I just missing the directions for this? Hoping there is a simply way the community has figured this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Windows to create a bootable Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/924676/how-to-use-windows-to-create-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-usb-flash-driv)

Comment: The above duplicate is incorrect. Your question is about a live/installation media for Ubuntu, not for Mac OSX as @Giacomo1968 suggests. To know: Ubuntu/Linux media can be created anywhere by any method available. It boots anywhere it can boot, period. You certainly misread/misunderstood those "directions". That you *can* make it in OSX doesn't mean you must just because the target machine is an Apple.

Comment: Now, the next question is: Can you install Ubuntu? As of now, for the new ARM based Macs it's either not possible or is a very hard, expert level, task; older Intel based machines should be almost as easy as any other PC.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Nice catch! I will assume the OP inherited an older, Intel-based Mac. If that is the case, basically creating a bootable USB in Windows should work fine.

Comment: Gents, gonna give this a go.  Thanks for all the advice!  If it works, I'll be sure to upvote the correct answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive)